# SWT Table with alternating row colors and sorting and filtering

Tags: user-interface, swt, jface, tableviewer

I'm working on adding alternating row colors to a SWT/JFace table by implementing ITableColorProvider in the label provider but when the table is sorted or filtered the table row colors don't hold their position. So I'll have white rows next to white rows and grey rows next to grey rows. I'm guessing this is happening because my elements are getting rearranged and the row color is going with them. Here's what I'm using that isn't working when the table is filtered or sorted:

```java
public Color getBackground(Object element)
 {
    ArrayList list = (ArrayList) tableViewer.getInput();
    int index = list.indexOf(element);
    if ((index % 2) == 0)
    {
        return gray;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

It works great until the table is altered by sorting or filtering. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use the `TableViewer` `getElementAt` call to search through the elements to find the index of the object. Use something like:

```java
private int findElementIndex(Object element)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < tableViewer.getTable().getItemCount(); i++) {
    Object elementAt = tableViewer.getElementAt(i);

    if (elementAt.equals(element)) 
      return i;
  }

  return -1; 
}
```

Note: This is going to be slow for a large table.

Comment: If you are able to use a `ColumnLabelProvider`you can also use the approach presented in [Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors.java). The `ColumnLabelProvider` provides access to the `TableItem`. The snippet tries to improve performance in that it buffers the most recently computed item index (see `OptimizedIndexSearcher`).

Comment: As @RüdigerHerrmann says using `ColumnLabelProvider` is a much better solution.